# go-pear.bat file won't install PEAR at all

Tags: php, pear

I just made a new install of WAMP on Windows 7 and I'm trying to get PEAR to work. Things are going wrong from the very beginning. When I try to execute the go-pear.bat file, it shows me this.

> phar
>   "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.1\PEAR\go-pear.phar"
>   does not have a signature Warning:
>   require_once(phar://go-pear.phar/index.php):
>   failed to open stream: pha r error:
>   invalid url or non-existent phar
>   "phar://go-pear.phar/index.php" in C:\
>   wamp\bin\php\php5.3.1\PEAR\go-pear.phar
>   on line 1236 Press any key to continue
>   . . .

How can I help it that the file doesn't have a signature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This blog-post might interest you : [Pear: “go-pear.phar” Does Not Have a Signature](http://latyr.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/bug-dans-php5-3-0-pear-bat/)

It explains how to change a configuration option in php.ini to avoid this error message, and what's said it for WAMP 2.0 and PHP 5.3, so might work in your case.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone comes here from Google: We fixed the `.phar` download yesterday on http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar.

In some circumstances (well, actually only on Windows :-)) the file could corrupt from the download. So for example, a lot of people wanted to download it and ended up copy-pasting the contents, etc..

We've asked some people on Windows to test and so far it worked for everyone I talked to. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, and no matter which browser I use, it seems to hang for a long time in the last 4% of the download.  Then when I try to run php go-pear.phar, I get the error "phar 'C:\Program Files\PHP\go-pear.phar' has a broken signature".  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't really know what would cause this - so the download doesn't complete at all?

Comment: It says it completes (after hanging, so it may be simply timing out), but the file does not work.  I got around it by deleting my install, and installing directly from the go-pear.php UI to get the current version, but as it stands now I can't upgrade should a new version come out.

Comment: Always upgrade with: `pear upgrade PEAR`. No need to reinstall anything. If you hop on IRC (EFNET: #pear), I can try to help you trouble-shoot everything else.

Comment: Unfortunately all IRC clients are blocked at my work.  However, the pear upgrade PEAR command did the trick.  I'm obviously new at using PEAR, and I had been following the instructions at http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php, but thanks to your help I'm up and running.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Let’s try this from the PEAR directory. cd PEAR and let’s try that again.

```
php.exe -d phar.require_hash=0 go-pear.phar
```

Now the PEAR install runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the go-pear.bat file won't run, try this procedure:

1. issue this command with cmd.exe:

   ```
   php -d phar.require_hash=0 go-pear.phar
   ```

   Allow the installer to edit php.ini.
2. Check the contents of PEAR_ENV.reg - located in the PEAR directory YOUR-PHP-INSTALL-PATH\PEAR\ folder (ex. c:\PHP\PEAR\PEAR_ENV.reg) to be sure it has the paths right. Edit as needed and run it. Check your path and environment variables for correctness, then do the same in go-pear.bat and php.ini (mine needed to be corrected to point correctly to my php.exe file).
3. Issue the

   ```
   pear
   ```

   command at the command line to test the path configuration. It will run and do everything but still can't install packages due to a missing dependency.
4. Download and uncompress Structures_Graph from the [PEAR](http://download.pear.php.net/package/Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tgz) website (direct link).The file has three folders - docs, Structures and tests. Copy the Structure folder into the YOUR-PHP-INSTALL-PATH\PEAR\ folder (ex. c:\PHP\PEAR\Structures).
5. Issue the command:

   ```
   pear install Structures_Graph
   ```

   Even though the files are present, Structures_Graph is not really installed unless you issue the above command.
6. Issue the command:

   pear update PEAR
7. Enjoy!

   Good luck and thanks to Marcos Roriz for the graph dependency half of my solution!

Comment: I followed these instructions, but it doesn't work for me with Zend Server CE - all I get is `downloading ... done ... ERROR: unable to unpack C:\...\Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tgz` ... any ideas?

Comment: **solved**: much simpler than this, just wipe out your PEAR installation and reinstall from the latest phar distributed on the PEAR website - no issues.